# How can I execute power analysis for a ratio metric?

Tags: bootstrap, statistical-power, ratio

I've looked into the Delta method and it looks tedious. I understand the computational performance gain to help when the dataset is quite large. I only have 200 individuals contributing data, so I believe that the bootstrap approach should be viable.

Could I get a pseudo-code approach to defining a power analysis function for ratio metrics?

**Edit**:

Adding more details.

Ratio metric where I have 200 individuals who will be divided evenly between treatment and control groups. Each individual will produce their own number of trials, some of which will be successes.

My null hypothesis is that the success rate is equal in groups. My alternative hypothesis is that the success rate is not equal.

For the experiment to have any practical significance, the effect size would need to be at least 2%.

Ideally to know how to know how to use observed data (individuals and the successes & trials that they produce) to determine the power of an experiment where the expected effect is 2% delta in ratio.

Alternatively, I'd like to know what's the minimum detectable effect given power of 80%.

(Both scenarios assume alpha of 5%).

Comment: Too much is missing or assumed in this question.  A power analysis pertains to a sampling procedure, a test statistic, a null hypothesis, and an alternative hypothesis expressed in terms of some kind of effect size.  Kindly supply that information in your post.  You already have the test statistic (at least vaguely): what about the rest?

Comment: @whuber, great call out- I've edited the prompt accordingly!